# EF foreign key not being created

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working with EF code first approach. Everything was working fine until I started using multiple primary keys in my classes. Here's one example:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class News : BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public string Headline { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Content> Paragraphs { get; set; }

    public bool IsQuick { get; set; }

    public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
}

public class Photo : BaseEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the command *Add-Migration* the *Photo_Id* foreign key is not being created.

Here's the result of running the command:

```
CreateTable(
"dbo.News",
c => new
    {
        Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        LanguageId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        Headline = c.String(),
        Description = c.String(),
        Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
        IsQuick = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
    })
.PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Id, t.LanguageId })
.ForeignKey("dbo.Photos", t => t.Id, cascadeDelete: true)
.Index(t => t.Id);

CreateTable(
"dbo.Photos",
c => new
    {
        Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        Description = c.String(),
        Date = c.DateTime(),
        Image = c.Binary(),
        Match_Id = c.Int(),
    })
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Matches", t => t.Match_Id)
.Index(t => t.Match_Id);
```

As you can see there's no *Photo_Id* key in the table creation.

Any ideas of what can I do?

Comment: what is the problem? The code says the `Id` column of the `News` table is an FK to the `Photos` table.

Comment: I edited the question to add the `Photo` entity script EF is creating

Comment: Please show the code for `Photo` class.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. It's there, in the main question.

Comment: Ok I do NOT understand why you keep mentioning *Photo_Id*, I do not see it in the `Photo` class or any other class.

Comment: The `News` class has a `Photo` entity as a property. A foreign key should be added when EF creates the script. If a remove the `LanguageId` from `News` entity the `Photo_id` key is automatically created, but not if I add the second primary key (`LanguageId`)

Comment: Not sure why it does that, but the solution it to just add the FK you want into the model. Also, maybe try fluent configuration.

Comment: I need someone to provide me some code in order to find a solution with this. I'm kind of desperate at the moment. I can't deploy my new website because of this problem.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: I think you have to add  this code to your news model to create foreignkey.

`[ForeignKey("Photo_id")]
public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
public int Photo_id { get; set; }`

Comment: @FromSouth What was the problem on this one?